# Workflow consuming webservice - Editing the address?

Tags: 2010, workflow, web-services

My State Machine Workflow (SP 2010) consumes an external Web Service that I have added as a Service Reference in Visual Studio.

The WCF Service is currently hosted in my local machine.
We have planned a deployment in the internal server (both the WCF and workflow).

However, the URL of the Service does not work yet because we didn't publish it yet. How does that going to work? Will it work if I just add the local service as the Service Reference and just edit the web.config in order to bind to the new URL?